# Set value of this in jquery

Tags: jquery, this

In Mootools, the value of the **this** variable within a function can be controlled:

```
function foo() {
  // do something with the this variable
}

var bar = foo.bind(some_object);

// Now bar does the same thing as foo, except
// the this variable is a reference to some_object
```

Can this be done in Jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery offers the `.proxy()` method. It basically does the same as `.apply()` or `.call()` and it's syntax looks like:

```
$.proxy(method, scope);
```

In your example it would be:

```
var bar = $.proxy(foo, some_object);
```

Ref.: [.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)